# Calculando Senha Aleatoria usando ArrayList e ResultSet em Java

Tags: java, array, postgresql

Bom dia, estou com uma duvida, preciso Calcular uma senha nova para cada Paciente quando passar por esse método:

```
 ps = getConexao().prepareStatement(SQL_VERIFICAR_PROTOCOLOS_PENDENTES); 
            ps.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(dto.getData().getTime()));
            ps.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(dto.getData2().getTime()));
            ps.setInt(3, dto.getIdCorp());
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) { // fazendo a Busca pelo ResultSet

           StringBuffer CalcSenha = new StringBuffer();  
           ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
           lista.add(rs.getString("nome"));
           lista.add(rs.getString("data_nascimento"));
           lista.add...........(pego dados do banco);

                for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
                    CalcSenha.append(lista.lista.get(0));
                    System.out.println("A senha calculada foi:" + CalcSenha);
                }

            }
```

O calculo é feito assim:

> primeira letra do nome,
>   posição 7 da data de nascimento;
>   posição 1 da data de nascimento;
>   posição 9 da data de nascimento;
>   posição 1 do prontuario;
>   idade com 3 posições;
>   Total= 6 caracteres

Eu consigo pegar esses dados já com Meu `ResultSet`, minha duvida é eu uso o `StringBuffer` dando append, como eu faço pra percorrer e pegar a primeira letra do Nome do Paciente, a 7 posição da data de Nascimento...... ???
Não to conseguindo, porque da maneira que está CalcSenha.append(lista.lista.get(0)); ele puxa o nome inteiro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pegar apenas a primeira letra do nome, você pode usar o método subString().

Ex.:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
                CalcSenha.append(lista.lista.get(0).subString(0,0));
                System.out.println("A senha calculada foi:" + CalcSenha);
            }
```

Para a data, precisará convertê-la em String antes, que pode ser feito utilizando o SimpleDateFormat:

```
Date date = lista.lista.get(1);
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String text = df.format(date);
```

Comment: fiz desse jeito mesmo, encontrei esse subString e fui parseando o que precisava. Obrigado.